# How to show ID in message box?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, messagebox

I am currently developing a website. I have an a code in my external js file

```
function DeleteConfirm(rfqcodeLB) {
    var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
    confirm_value.type = "hidden";
    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete" + rfqcodeLB +" ?")) {
        confirm_value.value = "Yes";
    } else {
        confirm_value.value = "No";
    }
    document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
}
```

What I want to do is get the id of the selected row in the gridview. What i did was transfer the selected code into  string which is rfqcodeLB. And then put the attribute to the button. But it shows null.

Can someone please help me? Thanks.

```
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="../Pictures/Icons/deleteblack.png" runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" ID="deleteBT" OnClientClick="return DeleteConfirm(ContentPlaceHolder1_rfqcodeLB);"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the id as the function parameter, instead of ContentPlaceHolder1_rfqcodeLB, use this.id.

Comment: This will only get you the ID of the ImageButton, not the ID of the selected row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the `RowIndex` to the JavaScript function. Not `this.id`, that will only get you the ID of the ImageButton.

```
<asp:ImageButton OnClientClick='<%# "return DeleteConfirm(" + Container.DataItemIndex + ");" %>' ImageUrl="../Pictures/Icons/deleteblack.png" runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" ID="deleteBT"/>
```

Or if you want a database value

```
OnClientClick='<%# "return DeleteConfirm(&#39;" + Eval("yourID") + "&#39;);" %>'
```